# storing values in array and display in vba powerpoint

Tags: arrays, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to check for red fonts in a powerpoint slide. I want to store the slide number that contain the red font in the array and display in a single dialog box. Currently it displays one slide number in one dialog box.

My current code looks like the following. Can anybody tell how can I store it an array and display it?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim x As Byte

    With ActivePresentation
        z = .Slides(.Slides.Count).SlideNumber
        MsgBox z, vbDefaultButton1, "Total Slides"
    End With

    Dim myarray() As Integer
    ReDim myarray(0 To 2)

    For i = 2 To z
        Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(i)

        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
                MsgBox i, vbDefaultButton2, "Slide with RED font"
            End If
        Next shp
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an array I'd use a [collection](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-collections/) like that

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
Dim x As Byte
Dim z, i

    With ActivePresentation
        z = .Slides(.Slides.Count).SlideNumber
        MsgBox z, vbDefaultButton1, "Total Slides"
    End With

    Dim myCol As Collection
    Set myCol = New Collection


    For i = 2 To z
        Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(i)
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
                ' MsgBox i, vbDefaultButton2, "Slide with RED font"
                myCol.Add CStr(i), CStr(i)
            End If
        Next shp
    Next

    Dim j As Long
    For j = 1 To myCol.Count
        Debug.Print myCol.Item(j)
    Next j


End Sub
```

Comment: Thats perfect. A bit different but does the same thing. Bingo